# Which JavaScript rotator slides the panels around instead of transitioning?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript

I've seen plenty of rotators in JavaScript (including those in jQuery and other libraries) but one stood out as quite different: instead of fading between panels or sliding them on- and off-screen, it actually made the current panel reduce in size and go and sit in a list of panels, the next of which would then expand to fill the main content area.

ASCII diagram:

```
+----------------------+------+
| 1                    | 2    |
|                      +------+
|                      | 3    |
|                      +------+
|                      | 4    |
+----------------------+------+
```

In the transition, 1 becomes smaller and slides to occupy the place of 4. 3 and 4 slide up one place. 2 becomes larger and slides to occupy the place of 1.

I've been searching Google for this effect, and my news feeds, because I'm sure I saw it in a post from one of the RSS streams I follow, but no joy. Any help would be much appreciated.